# How to move an Object in a Zoomed Canvas following the mouse

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a Canvas within a Scrollviewer(with ZoomMode="true"). In the canvas there is Grid that I can move with the mouse

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled"   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Canvas x:Name="sala"  Width="3000" Height="3000">
        <Grid x:Name="tavolo1" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200"  ManipulationDelta="UIElement_OnManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="All" Width="100" Height="200" >
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</Scrollviewer>
```

The function in code-behind that permits this operation is:

```
private void UIElement_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid stackDragged = (Grid) sender;
    (stackDragged.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    (stackDragged.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

When I move the grid without zoom, the Grid's coordinates in Canvas become the coordinates of the mouse;
but when I do this with Zoom, the "Translation" of the Grid scale with the zoom, so that The Grid doesn't take the real coordinates of the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [ManipulationDelta.Translation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.manipulationdelta.translation) is measured in screen coordinates, you need to apply relative transform to it for obtaining actual translation-delta for the Grid in the ScrollViewer.

```
    private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var stackDragged = (Grid)sender;
        var transform = stackDragged.TransformToVisual(null).Inverse;

        var delta = transform.TransformPoint(e.Delta.Translation);
        var extra_offset = transform.TransformPoint(new Point());

        (stackDragged.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).X += delta.X - extra_offset.X;
        (stackDragged.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).Y += delta.Y - extra_offset.Y;

       // (stackDragged.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
       // (stackDragged.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

    }
```